# Fire keyup event in unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Whats the best way to trigger a keyup event in unit test. I'm using busterjs and wann test some key events on an input element. To be more clear. I know about createEvent/dispatch Event. I'm logging to simpler solution. Maybe I should use just jquery in my tests to trigger the events. There is [something simular](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.UserAction.html) in YUI as well. So after all I'm looking for a small library that just triggers the events.

Answer (score 0):

Try take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

Comment: I've update my question to make it more clear what I'm looking for.